# Could not load file or assembly 'xx.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.?

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I am having third party dll called "xx.DLL",i included in my web project, i copied and paste the project into IIS wweroot folder.I am using IIS7.5,then when i try to browse my application, i am getting the following error **"Could not load file or assembly 'xx.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found."**

Its working fine in local PC's, but when i try to host and browse in **Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Service Pack 1(64-bit OperationSystem)** i am getting the following error.

I don't know what is the problem ?
Any ideas?